# Instead Of Insert trigger doesn't work for my insert via C# code

Tags: c#, sql-server, triggers

I have the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_or_update_AccountNews
ON AccountNews
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE
        @AccountNumber bigint,
        @NewsId int,
        @TariffPlan nvarchar(1024)

    SELECT @AccountNumber = INSERTED.AccountNumber,
           @NewsId = INSERTED.NewsId,
           @TariffPlan = INSERTED.TariffPlan
    FROM INSERTED

    IF EXISTS (SELECT NewsId FROM [AccountNews] 
               WHERE AccountNumber = @AccountNumber AND NewsId = @NewsId)
        UPDATE [AccountNews]
        SET TariffPlan  = @TariffPlan
        WHERE AccountNumber = @AccountNumber
          AND NewsId = @NewsId
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO [AccountNews] (NewsId, AccountNumber, TariffPlan)
            SELECT @NewsId, @AccountNumber, @TariffPlan
END;
```

And I have a table, as you can see, that is called `AccountNews`. It has the following columns:

```
AccountNumber, NewsId, TariffPlan
```

The idea is when I insert something into the table the trigger will determine if the data exists (I have unique constraint by `AccountNumber` and `NewsId`) or not exists. If the data not exists - the insert, otherwise - update.

And it works perfectly via the SQL console, like:

```
insert into  AccountNews (NewsId, AccountId, TariffPlan) 
values (12345, 777777, 'Hello world');

insert into  AccountNews (NewsId, AccountId, TariffPlan) 
values (12345, 777777, 'Hello world 2');
```

Next, I have this C# code to insert data:

```
DataTable table = await ReadAsStringAsync(file, newsId);

var connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("MyDbConnection");

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlBulkCopy bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
{
    connection.Open();

    bcp.BatchSize = 1000;

    bcp.DestinationTableName = "[dbo].[AccountNews]";

    bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("NewsId", "NewsId");
    bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("AccountNumber", "AccountNumber");
    bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("TariffPlan", "TariffPlan");
    bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("Date", "Date");

    await bcp.WriteToServerAsync(table);
}
```

In this case I don't see a result of my trigger. When I load some data that is already in my database I have a unique constraint exception.

Comment: Your trigger is flawed, it assumes an `INSERT` only affects one row; that simply isn't true. The Trigger is working exactly as you wrote it; to do the process to **one arbitrary row** in the `INSERT` stateemnt.

Comment: In addition to what @Larnu said, you also have to opt into triggers being fired at all via `SqlBulkCopyOptions`.

Comment: @Larnu what do you mean? Am I have a set of rows in Inserted, or what?

Comment: `SELECT @AccountNumber = INSERTED.AccountNumber FROM INSERTED`, for example @Aleksej_Shherbak , means assign an arbitrary value (arbitrary as there's no `ORDER BY`) from the pseudo table `inserted` to the **scalar** variable `@AccountNumber`. So, if you have 1000 rows in the `inserted` pseudo table, your `TRIGGER` will go on to do it's logic for that one arbitrary value (the one assigned to the variable), and that's it. No process will be done for the other 999 values/rows.

Comment: Have a read of [Bad Habits to Kick : Abusing triggers](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers)

Comment: To clarify for the OP in case of any misconception, a trigger is invoked once per `batch` not per `row`. The `inserted` and `deleted` virtual tables contain `all rows` affected by the insert/update/delete, whether that was 1 row or 1 million rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an UPSERT-only table you can add a trigger like this:

```
use tempdb
go

drop table if exists AccountNews 

create table AccountNews
( 
  AccountNumber bigint,
  NewsId int,
  TariffPlan nvarchar(1024),
  constraint pk_AccountNews 
    primary key (AccountNumber, NewsId)
)
go
CREATE TRIGGER insert_or_update_AccountNews
ON AccountNews
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    merge AccountNews as target
    using (select * from inserted) as source
    on (target.AccountNumber = source.AccountNumber and target.NewsId = source.NewsId)
    when matched then
        update set TariffPlan = source.TariffPlan
    when not matched then
        insert (AccountNumber, NewsId, TariffPlan)
        values (source.AccountNumber, source.NewsId, source.TariffPlan);
END;
```

or wihout MERGE (which doen't permit duplicates within a single batch):

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_or_update_AccountNews
ON AccountNews
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    with q as
    (
      select a.*, i.TariffPlan NewTariffPlan
      from AccountNews a 
      join inserted i
        on a.AccountNumber = i.AccountNumber
       and a.NewsId = i.NewsId
    )
    update q set TariffPlan = NewTariffPlan;

    insert into AccountNews(AccountNumber,NewsId,TariffPlan)
    select AccountNumber,NewsId,TariffPlan
    from inserted i
    where not exists
    (
       select * 
       from AccountNews a
       where a.AccountNumber = i.AccountNumber
         and a.NewsId = i.NewsId
    );
END;

go
```

And you opt-in for triggers and constraint checking with [SqlBulkCopyOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopyoptions), which you should normally do when bulk loading from an application because bypassing constraints or triggers requires ALTER TABLE privileges on the table.